# The Propriety of Ralbag's Benefits: Pshat v. Drash?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, megillat-esther, middos-character-traits, ralbag

The Ralbag famously includes lists of lessons/benefits after sections of Tanach. FE, at the beginning of his Esther benefits:

> התועלה הראשון הוא במדות. והוא שראוי לשמוח בטוב בהימצאו, כאומרו "ביום
> טובה היה בטוב" (קהלת ז:יד). ולזה סיפר שאחר שהראה המלך רוב "עשר כבוד
> מלכותו" ו"יקר תפארת גדולתו" עשה זה המשתה הגדול "לכל שריו ועבדיו" ו"לכל
> העם הנמצאים בשושן הבירה למגדול ועד קטן" שבעת ימים.

Does this mean that the Ralbag thinks it was a *good idea* for Achaverosh to have a banquet?

Per Talmud Megilla 11b, however, the timing of Achashverosh's banquet is to malevolently celebrate/mark the fact that per his reckoning seventy years had passed and the Jews' return to Zion had not occurred. He then brings out temple vessels/defiles them while partying hard!

Is the Ralbag ignoring this evil motive? Pshat v. Drash? Seems pretty audacious to laud the king for his party!

Comment: Ah, you must be new to Ralbag...

Comment: Interesting question! Do you think that perhaps it need not be set up as a binary? People can have more than one motive behind a given action. Also, celebrating the good in a time of good is a true idea as we see in the Ralbag's quoted verse in Qoheleth, however that does not mean that what one perceives as good is in fact good. If Ahasaures had a distorted concept of the "good" it doesn't detract from the propriety of celebrating good on its occasion. Sidenote: It is generally encouraged around here to provide a translation or at least paraphrase quotations.